# How to send parameter and body both using Alamofire separately?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire to send parameter and body both. I have seen tutorials and read QA where people use parameters to use as body too as in this one:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "fullName": fullName,
            "mobileNumber": mobileNumber,
            "password": password
        ]
Alamofire.request(requestAddress , method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { response in
// utility
}
```

I am not sure how I should send body not using parameters as I need to send both parameters and body both.

Comment: I think you need to construct yourself the `URL` containing the parameters. With `QueryItems` it should be doable (see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932235/urlcomponents-queryitems-losing-percent-encoding-when-mutated)

Comment: Why do you need to pass the body actually where you can pass header, parameters even image-data for multipart?

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass your request body with `Parameters` or as `Data` with a `URLRequest` object. My guess is that you can't make it happen both. If you also like to pass over some information as queryString parameters you can do it by setting them in a `URLRequest` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42411188/5143524).

```
urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```